# Where is the canonical Microsoft TFS user guide?

Tags: version-control, tfs, azure-devops

I just want to know really simple things, like

- what on earth does Pending Change: "edit , [more]" mean?
- how do I interpret the Excluded Changes tree in the Pending Changes window?

This is easy to find out for Hg and Git. Why do Microsoft make it so difficult to discover for TFS?

Comment: It should be mandatory to add a comment when voting for question to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I hate TFS as much as anyone, but the specifics you listed are pretty clear.

The first one means that the changes included an edit and one or more others, e.g. Merge.
The second is pretty straight forward. The Excluded changes will not be included in the change set.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. The first point is extremely unclear. It implies that more is happening than just "edit". The second sounds simple when you put it like that, but the items listed in my excluded changes tree seem to include a load of files that haven't actually changed so I'm still not sure.

Comment: Any file that has been checkout out by you will show up in the changes; regardless of whether you have actually changed it or not. Some file get checked out automatically when you open a solution; and will, therefor, show up in your changes. When you check in the changeset, TFS will see that there are no real changes and exclude those files from the changeset. It is a very annoying "feature".